# How to handle large PL/pgSQL Functions migration with Flyway?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-migration, flyway

We are using Flyway to manage database migration (PostgreSQL but my question is not vendor specific).

So we have one directory per schema with one migration file per schema version. It's working well for structure change and adding small functions.

But now, I'm working on a large PL/pgSQL set of functions, for which we need to track history easily and we also need to split in several files for clarity. 
So we would like to have these functions in a separate file(s) and to have these files included in the Flyway patch file when we need to update it.

I didn't find a way to do that with Flyway, is it possible to do it? Or is there another way to deal with this case?

Comment: How did you deal with this?

Comment: We actually didn't handle this with Flyway but with our application update mechanism which is RPM.